# MonoTouch. Rotating background image

Tags: background, xamarin.ios, uiimage

I've applied a background image to my ViewController:

```
ParentViewController.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage (image)
```

Now, when screen orientation gets changed it breakes my entire background thing, because that picture stays as it was. Of course I could just rotate the image in Photoshop and put it in my project, but my humble pride of software engineer revolted.

I've searched through many sources. I've tried objective-c samples. I find only a few in c#. I don't have any time to learn differences between UIKit and Core Graphics. I've tried `CGContext.RotateCTM`, I've tried to achieve that with `CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation`. It doesn't work. I just need a simple thing to be done.

Apparently before using `RotateCTM` or changing `CGAffineTransform` you have to somehow define the pivotal point.

Please somebody show me a simple example, how it works.

Upd:

This is what I got so far:

```
var image = new UIImage ("Images/background.jpg");
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft) {
   CGImage imageRef = image.CGImage;
   var width = imageRef.Width;
   var height = imageRef.Height;
   CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = imageRef.AlphaInfo;
   CGColorSpace colorSpaceInfo = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB ();
   CGBitmapContext bitmap = 
           new CGBitmapContext (IntPtr.Zero, width, height, imageRef.BitsPerComponent, imageRef.BytesPerRow, colorSpaceInfo, alphaInfo);

   bitmap.TranslateCTM(0, imageRef.Height);
   bitmap.RotateCTM((float)-1.5707f);
   bitmap.DrawImage (new Rectangle (0, 0, height, width), imageRef);
   image = UIImage.FromImage (bitmap.ToImage());
   bitmap = null;
}
ParentViewController.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage (image);
```

and as you can see it ain't no good, though it does rotate:

[image: portrait][image: landscape]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a `UIImageView` as subview to your controller's view and load your image into that subview.
You might want to set the `ContentMode` of the `UIImageView` to `ScaleFit` to make it resize.
Set the `AutoresizingMask` of your `UIImageView` to `FlexibleWidth` and `FlexibleHeight` and you should get the desired result and rotation (as long as your controller override `ShouldAutorotateToOrientation()`).

```
var imageView = new UIImageView( UIImage.FromFile( pathToYourImage ) );
```

EDIT SAMPLE CODE:

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace Rotate
{
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        // class-level declarations
        UIWindow window;

        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            // create a new window instance based on the screen size
            window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
            window.RootViewController = new TestController();
            // make the window visible
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

            return true;
        }
    }

    public class TestController : UIViewController
    {
        public TestController() : base()
        {
        }

        public override void LoadView ()
        {
            base.LoadView ();
            this.imgView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("img.png"));
            imgView.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, 300, 300);
            this.imgView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
            this.imgView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin;
            this.View.AddSubview(this.imgView);
        }
        private UIImageView imgView;

        public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
        {
            this.imgView.Center = new System.Drawing.PointF(this.View.Bounds.Width / 2, this.View.Bounds.Height / 2);
            base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
        }

        public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: no it doesn't work. I want when the device changes its orientation it should also rotate the image 90 degrees. It doesn't

Comment: Have you tried it? I have added some code to prove that it is working as I explained to you.

Comment: Sorry... apparently I was trying it the wrong way... my apologies. Thank you for detailed sample code.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong but still it doesn't work on me... Did they change something in Ios 5?

Comment: This code was tested on iOS 5. What's wrong if you just take it and build it?

Comment: No I'm not saying that your code in non-functional, no. It's my own fault. I've just tried to apply it to my solution, and it didn't work. Obviosuly I'm missing something.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know: does MY code work on YOUR machine? Maybe it's a config issue? You can post your code here and we'll figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

This might qualify as an inappropriate use of FromPatternImage. In this case the resulting "UIColor" is not a view and does not qualify to receive any rotation events. Therefore you might be able to calculate bounds change, rotate the image, apply the newly calculated bounds, reset the BackgroundColor property all inside WillRotateToInterfaceOrientation(...) but that's pretty convoluted and not even remotely performant.

In my opinion the more sane path is to simply create a UIImageView and place it below everything else in the hierarchy:

```
var imageView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("Images/background.png"));
imageView.Frame = new RectangleF(...) // set appropriate frame here
imageView.AutoResizingMask = ...; // set appropriate mask here
ParentViewController.View.AddSubView(imageView);
ParentViewController.View.SendSubviewToBack(imageView);
```

This allows the system to assume responsibility for stuff it's designed to do, and keep you from having to write expensive rotation code all while achieving the desired effect.

Comment: you mean I got to have one image for portrait mode and another for landscape?

Comment: That's what I proposed already but the poster claimed the UIIMageView would not work. I have updated my answer to demonstrate the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

It might be overkill for just an image, but for rotation I've been using this...

https://github.com/escoz/monotouch-controls/blob/master/UICatalog/RotatingViewController.cs