# How to position UITableView (MonoTouch)

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, uitableview

Given the following code:

```
public class MainTableController : UITableViewController
{
    // Allow us to set the style of the TableView
    public MainTableController(UITableViewStyle style) : base(style)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {   
        TableView.DataSource = new MainTableDataSource();
        TableView.Delegate = new MainTableDelegate(this);

        TableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(UIImage.FromFile ("Content/Background-Home@2x.png"));

        TableView.Bounces = false;

        base.ViewDidLoad ();
    }
}
```

Given the following output:

[image]

How can I update my code so that the group of table cells starts halfway down the page?  The actual pixels aren't important, I am just trying to figure out where properties are to modify this.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea to manually position the UITableView in a UITableViewController. That being said I think adjusting the ContentInset property should get you where you need to go:

```
this.TableView.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets(this.TableView.Center.Y, 0, 0, 0);
```

This should push down the first Section / Cell to the specified UIEdgeInset.Top value.

**Edit:** As per clarification in comments...

If you need to maintain position of the background view...you might have better luck by creating a HeaderView for the first section and increasing it's frame to a size sufficient enough to move the first cell down:

```
public override UIView GetViewForHeader (UITableView tableView, int sectionIdx)
{
    if(sectionIdx == 0) { 

        // adjust appropriate index above ^

        var view = new UIView();
        view.Frame = new RectangleF(...) // adjust your frame here
        return view;    
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the harm in manually positioning?  I am new to this and if you can suggest a better solution to accommodate my needs, please let me know because I'd like to conform to best practices.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Generally a UIViewController's view (a UITableViewController just inherits from UIViewController) *always* wants to be fullscreen unless it uses the custom container APIs in iOS 5.x. Bottom line: They've documented that you'll get wonky behavior if manually position, and they've prescribed better ways of doing it. The above code should get you the desired effect though.

Comment: Thanks.  This might be a different question, but if you notice in my code above, I have a background image in use.  When I implement your solution, it pushes the background image down as well.  The reason for this question initially is because there is actually a logo behind the UITableView that I need visible.  Your solution pushes the UITableView down but with the image as well.

Comment: Ok, I adjusted the answer to reflect the clarification. Also I would avoid setting the BackgroundColor using UIColor.FromPatternImage because it does not adjust itself given rotation events. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333730/monotouch-rotating-background-image